# SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the error I get:

> ddlRankEdit' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not
>   exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

I have a form wiht several dropdownlists that are nested in a panel that is by default set to invisible. When a user selects a record from a separate list box the selected index changed event sets the panel to visible and makes a data call. That's when the error happens. See the code below, I added XXX where it stalls.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlRankEdit" CssClass="txtfield" DataSourceID="ODCRanks"
  DataTextField="Rank" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
  <asp:ListItem Text="--- Select a Rank ---" Value="-1" />                                            
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODCRanks" runat="server" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetRanks" 
    TypeName="RanksTableAdapters.RankTableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

protected void lboxManageMembers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlReviewMemberDetails.Visible = false;
    pnlUnlockUserAccount.Visible = false;
    pnlAdmins.Visible = false;
    pnlCreateAdmins.Visible = false;
    lblNote.Visible = false;
    pnlManageMenbers.Visible = true;

    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    DataSetTableAdapters.MemberInfoTableAdapter da = new DataSetTableAdapters.MemberInfoTableAdapter();

    Guid _memberId = Guid.Empty;
    _memberId = new Guid(lbxManageMembers.SelectedValue);
    DataSet.MemberInfoDataTable dt = da.GetMember(_memberId);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataSet.MemberInfoRow mr = dt[0];

   XXX ddlRankEdit.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(mr.rankid);
   XXX ddlPatrolEdit.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(mr.patrolid);
   XXX ddlPositionEdit.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(mr.bsaposid);

        txtFirstNameEdit.Text = mr.firstname;
        txtLastNameEdit.Text = mr.lastname;
        txtEmailEdit.Text = user.Email;
        txtAddressEdit.Text = mr.address;
        txtPhoneEdit.Text = mr.phone;
        txtCellPhoneEdit.Text = mr.altphone;
        txtAltEmailEdit.Text = mr.altemail;

        txtMotherFirstNameEdit.Text = mr.parentfn;
        txtMotherLastNameEdit.Text = mr.parentln;
        txtMotherWorkPhoneEdit.Text = mr.parentworkphone;
        txtMotheHomePhoneEdit.Text = mr.parentworkphone;
        txtMotherCellkPhoneEdit.Text = mr.parentscellphone;
        txtMotherTwitterEdit.Text = mr.parenttwitter;
        txtMotherEmailEdit.Text = mr.parentemail;
        txtMotherAltEmailEdit.Text = mr.parentemailalt;

        txtFatherFirstNameEdit.Text = mr.parent2fn;
        txtFatherLastNameEdit.Text = mr.parent2ln;
        txtFatherWorkPhoneEdit.Text = mr.parent2workphone;
        txtFatherHomePhoneEdit.Text = mr.parent2workphone;
        txtFatherCellPhoneEdit.Text = mr.parent2cellphone;
        txtFatherTwitterEdit.Text = mr.parent2twitter;
        txtFatherEmailEdit.Text = mr.parent2email;
        txtFatherAltEmailEdit.Text = mr.parent2emailalt;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you exactly what is happening: the value, for example stored in mr.rankid, is not present in the dropdownlist.

You need to figure out whether or not the dropdownlist contains the correct value or the value you are trying to assign does not exist in the list of available values.

**Update**

Since it is the visibility of the containing panel that seems to be causing the problems, it would be better to hide the panel using CSS than setting the `Visible` property to false, which will prevent it from rendering to the page.

This can be done with code similar to the following in the code-behind:

```
Panel1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility, "Hidden");
Panel1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "None");
```

Comment: Is this a lifecycle issue due to the panel being set to invisible? Data is correct.

Comment: I had thought there might be a page lifecycle issue, but I just tested this on a small project and found that the values are posted back correctly even if the DDList's visibility is set to false. The only way I reproduce this problem is to use a value that wasn't actually in the list of values within the dropdown list.

Comment: Not sure how you did it as I made the panel visible from the start and then on postback there was no error.

Comment: Is it just a standard panel or an update panel? I had no issues with a standard panel, but there could be other issues. Since setting Visible to true fixes the problem, the solution is to hide the panel using CSS attributes. I have updated the answer to show how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

modify your code like this:

```
if (dataTable1.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString() != "" && dataTable1.Rows[0]["columnName"] != null)
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(dataTable1.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this codes for use dropdownlist in editemplate when you dont need to use a datasource  :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="state" SortExpression="state">
          <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Style="position: relative"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("state") %>'  >
       <asp:ListItem Value="approved">approved</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="notapproved">notapproved</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
         </EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```